# how to provide different set of parameters to different instances of browser in Protractor

Tags: protractor

i got multiCapabilities set in the config as

```
multiCapabilities : [{
  browserName : "chrome",
  shardTestFiles: true,
  maxInstances: 2,
  //set the window size
  chromeOptions : {
      args : ['--lang=en', '--window-size=1024,768']
  }
}]
```

So, Let's say i got two instances of Chrome browser running and i got two sets of parameters. How can i provide each set of parameters to those two Chrome browser so that they run on different info like one instance running on USERID1 and other instance on USERID2?